# How much does it cost to train a yolov3 neural net from scratch?

Tags: tensorflow

I was wondering if someone had done the math (or something similar) on how much it costs to train a neural net (around the size of yolov3) from scratch? I ask because I have been training yolov3 for like 6 days on a titan rtx gpu. I was thinking of trying out something like AWS, but I don't have any idea how much training that net from scratch would cost.

Comment: This depends on a lot of other factors. How much training data do you have, what is your whole pipeline, how much accuracy or loss are you aiming for, ... Please try to be more specific with your question.

Comment: the standard yolov3 training on the coco dataset is 45000 epochs